# x64, why does the following assembly cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, 64-bit

I have the following assembly code:

```
.data
.text

entry_point:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    popq %rbp
    ret

.global _main
_main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    call entry_point
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

On my MacBook it compiles and runs fine, but I've just tried to make it run on Linux/Ubuntu 17.x and it gives me a segmentation fault. I ran it with GDB and it just tells me there is a SIGSEGV in ?? (), ... nothing really useful.

After checking with LLDB it tells me that:

```
... SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x1)
memory read failed for 0x0
```

Still not really sure what this means however, and I don't know why it seg faults since the program, to me, is two functions with a stack frame setup and a simple call?

The entry point to my program is the `_main` procedure. libc is linked with my assembly program.

As per the suggestion, I re-wrote my assembly program to use a system exit call instead of "ret":

```
.data
.text
entry_point:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    popq %rbp
    ret

.global main
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    call entry_point
    popq %rbp
    movq $60, %rax
    movq $2, %rdi
    syscall
```

And I run this program as:

```
as foo.s -o foo.o
ld foo.o -lc
./a.out
```

But I get the following:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004001d3
```

Comment: On linux you can't use `ret` to end your program. You need an exit syscall. It's not quite clear whether you are using libc or not, also which one is your actual entry point.

Comment: @Jester I think this solves my problem, I did not know this... will update my question to clarify however

Comment: On Linux it needs to be `main`. not `_main` if linking with the C startup

Comment: @MichaelPetch Interesting, why is that? Why does OS X not mind the underscore?

Comment: Because OS/X uses MACHO and Linux uses ELF.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh wow, I'll read up on these. This should make my life a whole lot easier, thank you

Comment: Change all references of `_main` to `main` in the code and then assemble and link with _GCC_ (easiest) with something like `gcc progname.s -o progname`  (where progname.s is whatever the name of your assembly file is).

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't want to use gcc, but I've updated my question to reflect your comment

Comment: _GCC_ in this case is just front ending for _LD_ but it goes out of its way to provide all the _C_ runtime library and dynamic loader options for you. GCC is literally calling `as` for you and using `ld` to do linking.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I know but I want to do it myself because I don't want to use someone elses compiler in my own compiler :) I've fixed the problem though by changing _main to main to _start, but this seems to contradict what you've said. Is it because gcc expects main or something?

Comment: Because you clearly don't understand what the _C_ startup runtime does when it calls main vs bypassing the _C_runtime on Linux and skipping right to `_start`. `_start` and `main` on Linux are not the same thing.

Comment: But in your case since you don't want to use _GCC_ you haven't included any of the _C_ startup runtime objects so there is no `_start` label and nothing to call `main`(adding `-lc` is the _C_ librayr but doesn't pull into the _C_ startup files). You can ask GCC to dump out the command line it uses to link but you don't want to use GCC so apparently looking at the linker line it uses is beyond the type of help you want.

Comment: You would likely have to do something convoluted like `ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o foo.o -lc -o foo --dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` . The directories may be different between versions of linux and particular compilers and it is different for 32-bit programs (if you were to generate those) which is exactly the reason why _GCC_ is the preferable front end to pull in the _C_ library and the _C_ runtime because it hides all the gory platform specific stuff.

Comment: I reverted your last change because it changed the nature of the original question and made it a new one. You do not provide an answer in your question. if you wish to self answer your own question then add an answer.

Comment: And using `-lc` without the _C_ startup code being run first can cause the _C_ library to fail. Most likely such failure would be seen if you spin off more than one thread. It is frowned upon to use `-lc` without the _C_ runtime unless you use some other C library (like MUSL) that doesn't require _C_ startup code to execute first for proper functioning.

Comment: Interesting, some stuff to read up about. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `ld foo.o -lc`

That command does not build a valid executable. In particular, libc requires certain initialization (usually performed by `crt0.o`, which is added by the compiler driver), and that initialization is not happening here.

Generally, you should *never* link user-level programs directly with `ld` -- use the compiler driver, such as `gcc` instead:

```
gcc foo.s
```

will build your program correctly.